# Renaming Custom User Model created by extending Abstract User

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I created a custom user model by extended AbstractUser. I now want to rename my model.

Ran make migrations but am getting an error

```py
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher: bool = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField('email address', blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
```

Class MyUser was earlier called User

```py
class TeacherProfile(PersonProfile):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Teacher Profiles'

    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='teacher_profile')
    doj = models.DateField("Date of Joining", null=True, blank=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='teacher/')
```

I also have onetoone relationship like so and

```py
class StudentProfile(PersonProfile):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Student Profiles'

    YEAR_CHOICES = []
    for r in range(1980, datetime.datetime.now().year + 1):
        YEAR_CHOICES.append((r, r))

    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='student_profile')
    gr_phone_no = models.CharField("Guardian's Phone No", max_length=10)
    yoe = models.IntegerField('year of enrollment', choices=YEAR_CHOICES,
                              default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='student/%Y/')
```

Am getting this error when i migrate

```
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'main.myuser', but app 'main' doesn't provide model 'myuser'.
The field main.StudentProfile.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'main.myuser', but app 'main' doesn't provide model 'myuser'.
The field main.TeacherProfile.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'main.myuser', but app 'main' doesn't provide model 'myuser'.
```

Project Structure is like so:
[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Could you share your project structure please?

Comment: Did you add the app where you defined `myuser` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: To be clear: `makemigrations` works fine, it's only when you try to apply them using `migrate` that it fails? The migrations produced by `makemigrations` look okay?

Comment: add `AUTH_USER_MODEL='applabel.MyUser'` in `settings.py`

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Yes its migrate that fails.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes I have

Comment: @JoãoVictorMonte Edited the post to include the structure